# How to stop text with sub/superscript and fraction in FrameLabel from being Italic?

Tags: labeling, fonts

The objective is to use a Roman (i.e., non-italic) font in `FrameLabel`.

Consider this

```
Plot[Sin[x Pi], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(x\), \(π\)]\)",
                 "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(0\)]\)"},
  LabelStyle -> {20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"}]
```

[image]

As you can see the `FrameLabel`s are in italics. I can prevent italics for $y^0$ by using `Superscript["y", "0"]`, but I could not find any way to handle the fraction.

```
Plot[Sin[x Pi], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, 
         FrameLabel -> {DisplayForm[FractionBox["x", "π"]], Superscript["y", "0"]}, 
         LabelStyle -> {20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"}]
```

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Why is `SuperScript` appearing in Roman but `SuperScriptBox` is appearing in Italic?
2. How to get a Roman font for the fraction?

I have not tried using `MaTeX` yet. I would like to see first if this problem can be fixed with a small tweak. I am using MMA11.1 in Linux.

Comment: Digits are simply set upright. That's common practice in mathematical typesetting since constants are not to set in italics. Numbers _are_ constants. Compare also to the practice in LaTeX. _In principle_, also $\pi$ should be an $\uppi$ (it is available in LaTeX by loading the package _upgreek_). Replace `Superscript["y", "0"]` with `Superscript["y", "z"]` and you will see that  exponents are set in italics in general.

Comment: Ah, now I see. The base `y` is also not in italics in your example. That's weird; it is typeset correctly in MMA 11.0.1 for macos. Maybe applying the `Style` to both framelabels _by hand_ would help.

Comment: Looks like `SingleLetterItalics` is switching `True` and `False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SingleLetterItalics` is controlling this behaviour. For example:

```
Plot[Sin[x Pi], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {DisplayForm[FractionBox["x", "\[Pi]"]], 
   DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["y", "0"]]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"}]
```

vs making the label two characters long

```
Plot[Sin[x Pi], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {DisplayForm[FractionBox["x", "\[Pi]"]], 
   DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["y2", "0"]]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"}]
```

If you want to stick with using `DisplayForm` and boxes then try this:

```
Plot[Sin[x Pi], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {DisplayForm[FractionBox["x", "\[Pi]"]], 
   DisplayForm[
    SuperscriptBox[Style["y", SingleLetterItalics -> False], "0"]]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike for `SingleLetterItalics`. Could you tell me how to make `SingleLetterItalics -> False` as default.

Answer (score 4):

The default format for [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) is [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm):

```
Options[GraphicsBox, FormatType]
```

> {FormatType -> TraditionalForm}

[`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) uses [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics):

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "TraditionalForm", SingleLetterItalics}]
```

> True

[`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics) displays single letter *variables* in italics. Note that single letter strings are not variables, and so they do not get italicized. So, in the following, the first output is in italics, while the second output is not:

```
y //TraditionalForm
"y" //TraditionalForm
```

> *y*
>
> y

So, three simple approaches to avoid italics are:

1. Use [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) (which has `SingleLetterItalics->False`)
2. Use strings instead of variables
3. Put your labels inside of a [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style) wrapper (e.g., `Style[y, Plain]` or `Style[y, SingleLetterItalics->False]`)

Now, for the question about why your example had a mixture of italic and plain variables. Mathematica typesetting converts expressions into boxes in order to show them in two-dimensional form. For example:

```
MakeBoxes[x/π, TraditionalForm] //InputForm
```

> FractionBox["x", "π"]

Notice the presence of the box form [`FractionBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionBox) and that the variable `x` and constant `π` have been converted to their symbol names `"x"` and `"π"`. One can use [`DisplayForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayForm) to print boxes inside an expression in explicit two-dimensional form (I prefer [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes) to [`DisplayForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayForm), because [`DisplayForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayForm) encourages the mixing of expressions and boxes, and I think they should never be mixed). Your first label:

```
DisplayForm[FractionBox["x", "π"]]
```

is thus equivalent to the typeset form of `x/π`, and so naturally in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) the `x` is displayed in italics. Your second label:

```
Superscript["y", "0"]
```

is just an expression, and so the "y" is not displayed in italics. If you had used:

```
DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["y", "0"]]
```

instead, then since [`SuperscriptBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SuperscriptBox) is a box form, `"y"` would be the box representation of the variable `y` and it would have been displayed in italics.

Here then are a few examples of a [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel) option that would not typeset anything in italics:

```
FrameLabel -> {"x"/π, "y"^"0"}
FrameLabel -> {"x"/π, HoldForm["y"^0]}
FrameLabel -> {
    Style[x/π, SingleLetterItalics->False],
    Style[Superscript[y,0], Plain]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @CarlWoll for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply `Style` to each axis label as well:

```
Plot[Sin[x Pi], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> (FontSlant -> Plain),
FrameLabel -> DisplayForm /@ {FractionBox@(Sequence @@ (Style[#, Plain] & /@ {"x","\[Pi]"})),
Superscript[Style["y", Plain], "0"]}, LabelStyle -> {20, Black, FontFamily -> "Times"}]
```

[image]